# Magento 2 : installation stuck at 67% every time

Tags: magento2, installation

I m trying to install magento2.1 with sample data but every time it stuck on 67%. 
As I check in console ....setup/index.php/session/prolong returning false every time. 
[image]

Please let me know what should I check to complete this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check below link and then try to install. 
Also Change in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html
    http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: Even though there are many same looking solutions, every newer magento version has the same issue.
Even i tried max_execution_time to 36000 (no need to tell that time and memory also) and still suffering from issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below options.

1. Increase max_execution_time in php.ini.
2. Apache mod_rewrite module must be enabled.
3. If still the issue exists try to install it by **composer**
4. Refer Magento 2 system requirements Documents.

Hope this helps.